# Create an array of buttons from a .txt file that can be filtered?

Tags: android, button, filter, text-files

I am working on a project and I've gotten a decent amount of the way through, I just have two questions right now that will put this part of the project to rest. For both of these questions I'll make a note saying that I have a text file called "gameslist.txt" in the assets folder. From what I've seen that is useful information to have when asking a question.

Q1: I want to create an array of Buttons with each button's text being the next line in the text file when the activity is created. So, the first button's text will be the first line in the text file, the second button's text will be the second line of the text file, so on and so forth for each line of the text file. There are 3622 lines of text in the file.

Q2: I have a series of buttons (# - Z). How can I get it so that when the user taps one of the buttons the only lines from the text file starting with that letter (or in # case anything that doesn't start with a letter) are shown?

I hope people can help me with this, and if you can help me with only one of my problems, that's fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want an ExpandableListView for this. So you'd ultimately have 3622 items divided into 26 (letters) + 10 (numbers) groups. However, that's still a very large amount of items to load. Search for tutorials on ExpandableListView, the bulk of your working code will be in the ExpandableListAdapter.

Comment: Would it be easier to create separate text files for each group. Then when the user taps the letter I clear whatever is loaded and then load the new text file?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. The adapter actively re-uses views for what is shown on the screen. I don't think that approach is necessary. I'd just focus on getting it working with a subset, and then seeing how it performs with the full file.